# Book where a time traveler is supposed to make an interview with Jesus

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

In this book, there was a time traveler guy who is supposed to make an interview with Jesus but he lost his memory if I remember correctly.

Comment: This is quite a brief description can you not remember anything else? How did he lose his memory? Why was he having an interview? When did you read this? If you have anything else to add you can [edit] your question to add those details in.

Comment: Also, obligatory mention that https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question has a bunch of questions you can try to address with your edits.

Comment: After he lost his memory, I'm guessing he meandered around the middle East for a while before (wait for it)... the big twist reveal that he is (wait for it) actually Jesus himself!! Bet you didn't see that coming.

Answer (score 0):

I did a google search for your question and the first suggestion that turned up was [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behold_the_Man_(novel)). It is a book called *Behold the Man*.

Read through the plot summary and it seemed to match all your requirements but one. There was no mention of memory loss in the synopsis. Maybe it was withheld from the synopsis because it was a major spoiler!? @Valorum, in his comment, was surprisingly close with his plot description to the actual book!

Let me know if this is the book. I might check it out this weekend.

Comment: There are a host of short stories (and novels) about time travelers meeting, killing, replacing and/or seducing Jesus. It's almost as tropey as the last man on Earth being revealed to be called Adam. And while '*Behold the Man*' is certainly ***an*** example of this trope, the protagonist isn't a journalist nor is he trying to conduct an interview, nor does he suffer from amnesia. I'd be very surprised if this turned out to be the right answer.

Comment: @Valorum While it is true that there are are many possible answers, that does not mitigate the fact that this is still a valid answer within the constraints provided.

Comment: @TheDaleks - I downvoted because, aside from the major trope, this answer in no way matches the story described. Even a few seconds of googling around would have revealed that